# jQuery - How to access Spring model object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, freemarker

I have a simple model object Employee within my Controller, and I would like to access that object in jQuery. My model has list of Phone numbers. I would like to iterate through this phone list in jQuery. I am using Freemarker Template Language. When I try to assign the model object to a javascript variable, I am getting the below exception.

```
For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence):
```

Below are my model and javascript files.

**Employee.java**

```
 public class Employee{
    private List<Phone> phoneNumbers;
    public List<Phone> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return this.phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<Phone> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers= phoneNumbers;
    }
 }
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
var phones = "${employee.phoneNumbers}" ;
```

Comment: try removing quotes. just use `var phones = ${employee.phoneNumbers} ;`

Comment: I tried that too. got the same error: "freemarker.core.NonStringException: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence):"

Comment: It is as the error says. When you're doing an evaluation `${...}`, it should be a string (number, date or boolean). Freemarker does not know it is suppose to create a javascript array. You need to build the array yourself from the freemarker model.